# Java eclipse error - Multiple Markers at this line - URL & SAXException cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a java code to validate XMLs against XSD file.
Eclipse shows 2 error in following code.

> **Multiple Markers at this line -**
>
> URL cannot be resolved to a type
>
> SAXException cannot be resolved to a type

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
    import javax.xml.transform.Source;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
    import javax.xml.validation.*;
    
    public class xml_validator_class {
     
      public static void main(String argv[]) {
          URL schemaFile = new URL("xsdfile.xsd");
          Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("xmlfile.xml"));
          SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
              .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
          Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
          Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
          try {
            validator.validate(xmlFile);
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
          } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
            System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }
          
          
      }
      
    }
```

Kindly refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file) for below program :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple markers error in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270096/multiple-markers-error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import the missing classes so that the unqualified types can be used in the program

```
import java.net.URL;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the underlined text, Eclipse is supposed to offer some suggestions, including a suggestion to import the classes.

Comment: @Reimeus: Now it says at URL -> Multiple markers at this line - unhandled exception type MalformedURLException

Comment: @Reimeus : After placing this, it says 
Multiple markers at this line - unhandled exception type  MalformedURLException ; 
unhandled exception type SAXException

Comment: @logan you have a number of checked exceptions which you need to handle - either surround the code in a `try/catch` or throw the exceptions from the method

Comment: it shows error at this line   Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
 what would be the exception ?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because you have used some classes from some other package and Compiler is ***not able to resolve those dependencies*** because of missing imports.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to Auto import all the required dependencies. Or use manual import as suggested by @Reimeus.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste 'URL' class somewhere in your machine with extension of .Java, delete URL class from  package, and copy URL Class paste on package folder,  Clean the projects. it's worked for me.